Solicitudes POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE no responden después de cierto tiempo en servidor Nginx con Express y PM2
Descripción:
Estoy ejecutando un backend con Nginx, Express.js, y gestionado por PM2 en un servidor de producción. El servidor funciona correctamente durante un tiempo, pero después de varias horas o días de operación, las solicitudes HTTP que realizan cambios de estado (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) dejan de recibir respuesta. No es que estas solicitudes tarden demasiado en responder, sino que simplemente no responden en absoluto.
Contexto técnico:

Backend: Express.js
Servidor web: Nginx
Manejador de procesos: PM2

Métricas observadas:

Event Loop Latency p95: 14.51 ms
Event Loop Latency: 5.97 ms
Active Handles: 70
Active Requests: 0
HTTP Requests per Minute: 0 req/min
HTTP P95 Latency: 4376 ms
HTTP Mean Latency: 106 ms
Used Heap Size: 48.54 MiB
Heap Usage: 90.6%
Heap Size: 53.57 MiB
Event Loop Latency p95 (duplicate): 14.48 ms
Event Loop Latency (duplicate): 5.96 ms
Uptime: 8h

Monitoreo:
Se realiza un seguimiento básico del rendimiento del servidor y de las rutas a través de métricas, pero no se observan problemas claros en los logs hasta que las solicitudes comienzan a no responder.
Problema recurrente:
Después de cierto tiempo de ejecución, las rutas POST, PUT, PATCH y DELETE dejan de responder completamente. Solo un reinicio del servidor (mediante PM2) resuelve temporalmente el problema.
Observaciones adicionales:
Las solicitudes GET parecen no verse afectadas o funcionan de manera más consistente que las rutas que realizan cambios de estado.
No se observan errores explícitos en los logs de Nginx o Express que indiquen la causa de este comportamiento.
Después de un reinicio con PM2, el servidor vuelve a funcionar correctamente, pero el problema se repite eventualmente.
Preguntas:
¿Cuáles podrían ser las causas de que las solicitudes POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE dejen de responder después de cierto tiempo en un backend basado en Express.js gestionado por Nginx y PM2?
Cualquier sugerencia o guía para diagnosticar y resolver este problema sería muy apreciada.
¡Gracias de antemano!

Como lo veo yo, son muchas preguntas para algo de tanta envergadura, ya que puede ser por tu código, la base de datos limitada, el nginx que bloquea las peticiones, el mismo pm2 por memoria, entre otras. Es difícil sino hay algún código de error que nos muestres.

Revisa las métricas en un momento del tiempo donde esos endpoint sí respondan. Toma nota de la memoria utilizada. Supongamos que sean 40MB. Prueba correr PM2 estableciendo que por encima de ese límite el worker se tenga que reiniciar. (usando el flag --max-memory-restart 40M). Esto es un proceso de prueba y error. Usando un límite muy bajo tu aplicación se reiniciará demasiado seguido y puede que eso tenga otras desventajas
